# start paint from the circle android

Tags: java, android, draw

I could program an application to draw but I have a problem

I want to start drawing from the circle, 
my starting point will always be the circle, how could I do that?

Now I can draw from any point, I tried to find the middle of the screen but it did not work

[image]

```
    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    path = new Path();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(20f);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mcanvas = new Canvas(mbitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    int a = metrics.widthPixels; // to get width of the screen
    int b = metrics.heightPixels;

    canvas.drawCircle(a/2,((b/2)-160),50, paint);
    if ((canDraw)) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}

private void startTouch (float x , float y){
    if ((canDraw)) {
    path.moveTo(x,y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y ;
}}
public void moveTouche (float x,float y ) {
    if ((canDraw)) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if(dx >= Tolerance || dy >= Tolerance){
        path.quadTo(mX,mY,(x+mX)/2,(y+mY)/2);
        mX = x ;
        mY = y;

    }}
}
private void upTouch(){
    if ((canDraw)) {
    path.lineTo(mX,mY);
}}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
   switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startTouch(x,y);
            invalidate();
            break ;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upTouch();
            invalidate();
            break ;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            moveTouche(x,y);
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
   return true ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- find the coordinates that delimit your central region from which touches must start, or create an element that identifies it
- inside `ouTouchEvent`, write this:

  ```
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      if (touchIsInsideCircle(x,y)) {
         startTouch(x,y);
         invalidate();
      }
      break ;
  ```
- define a function that knows the center of the screen by using the coordinates predefined:

  ```
   boolean touchIsInsideCircle(float x, float y) {
       return (x < maxX && x > minX && y < maxY && y > minY);
   }
  ```

Comment: so i tried with this  
`private boolean touchIsInsideCircle(float x, float y) {
        int a = metrics.widthPixels; // to get width of the screen
        int b = metrics.heightPixels;
            return (x < a/2 && x > a/2 && y <((b/2)-160)  && y >((b/2)-160)) }` 
Those are the coordinates of the circle, the problem the drawing always starts with x == 0 and y == 0 and every time I touch the screen the points are connected